# Confusion about the inputs array of useEffect(React Hooks API)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Some React Hooks API like `useEffect`, `useMemo`, `useCallback` have a second parameter: an array of inputs:

```
useEffect(didUpdate, inputs);
```

As the official document said:

@see [Conditionally firing an effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)

1. > That way an effect is always recreated if one of its inputs changes.
2. > every value referenced inside the effect function should also appear in the inputs array.

So we can see, the `inputs` array takes two responsibilities.
In most situations, they are working properly. But sometimes they conflict.

For example, I have a little counting program, it does two things:

1. Click button and the count plus 1.
2. Send the count to server every 5 seconds.

Codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/k0m1mq9v

Or see the code here:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

function xhr(count) {
  console.log(`Sending "${count}" to my server.`);
  // TODO send count to my server by XMLHttpRequest
}

function add1(n) {
  return n + 1;
}

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // Handle click to increase count by 1
  const handleClick = useCallback(
    () => setCount(add1),
    [],
  );

  // Send count to server every 5 seconds
  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => xhr(count), 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Example;
```

When I run this code, I'll always send `count = 0` to my server, because I haven't passed the `count` to `useEffect`.

But if I pass `count` to `useEffect`, my `setInterval` will be cleared and the whole callback will be recreated each time when I click the button.

I think maybe there's another paradigm to achieve my goal which I haven't think of. If not, that is a conflict of the `inputs` array.

Comment: The scenario you have here is definitely valid, though I find it rather specific to the characteristic of the `setInterval` function and maybe also the [limitation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions) that hooks can only be called from React function.

Comment: @ClaireLin `setInterval` is just an example. `WebSocket`, `setTimeout`, `addEventListener`, `XMLHttpRequest`, etc. They all have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Reply from React：

[React discussion Github](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14543#issuecomment-452713416)

A better solution may be implemented, but not now.

But life will continue, so a workaround pattern like [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14543#issuecomment-452676760) may help:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const countRef = useRef(count);
useEffect(() => {
  countRef.current = count
}, [count]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`useRef()` can solve your problem. I think this is an elegant solution: [code in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/m1y7vl0vp)

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // ***** Initialize countRef.current with count
  const countRef = useRef(count);

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => setCount(add1), []);

  // ***** Set countRef.current to current count
  // after comment https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14543#issuecomment-452996829
  useEffect(() => (countRef.current = count));

  useEffect(() => {
    // ***** countRef.current is xhr function argument
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => xhr(countRef.current), 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**EDIT**

After comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14543#issuecomment-452996829